# OpenCV: How to show rotated angle as text on image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, opencv

My goal is to create an image that includes rotated angles as text within each boundary. The image should include colored boundaries (which I figured out) and **the angle value within each boundary** (which I didn't figure out).

## PYTHON CODE

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np
import csv


mask = cv2.imread('patch_mask.png')
mask = cv2.resize(mask, (400, 400))
mask_gray = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret2, th2 = cv2.threshold(mask_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)  # Otsu's 
method
image = cv2.imread('patch_image.png')
image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image_enhanced = cv2.equalizeHist(image_gray)

# process image
boundary_output = "/Desktop/mat2py/mask_boundary.png"
ellipse_output = "/Desktop/mat2py/ellipse.png"
colormap_output = "/Desktop/mat2py/colormap.png"
# im = cv2.imread("patch_mask.png")
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)

# find contours in the binary image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
tmp = np.zeros_like(mask)
tmp2 = np.zeros_like(mask)
boundary = cv2.drawContours(tmp, contours, -1, (255, 255, 255), 1)

# calculate moments and extract cell shape info
moment_dict = {}
for index, cnt in enumerate(contours):
    moment_dict[index] = cv2.moments(cnt)

# creating a csv file named coordinates
with open('/Desktop/mat2py/coordinates.csv', 'w', newline='') as newFile:
    newFileWriter = csv.writer(newFile)
    newFileWriter.writerow(
        ["Center_x", "Center_y", "(Center_x, Center_y)", "(Major Axis, Minor Axis)", "Rotation Angle"])

obj_properties = {}
for index, obj_moments in moment_dict.items():
    cx, cy = obj_moments['m10'] / obj_moments['m00'], obj_moments['m01'] / obj_moments['m00']
    ellipse = (x, y), (MA, ma), angle = cv2.fitEllipse(contours[index])
    props = {'Center_x': cx, 'Center_y': cy, 'Major Axis': MA, 'Minor Axis': ma, 'Rotated Angle': angle}
    ellipse_image = cv2.ellipse(imgray, ellipse, (255, 0, 255))
    obj_properties[index] = props
    newFileWriter.writerow([cx, cy, (x, y), (MA, ma), angle])

all_the_angle = [v['Rotated Angle'] for k, v in obj_properties.items()]
min_angle = 0
max_angle = 180
range_angle = max_angle - min_angle

# color mapping of Rotated Angle scalars to BGR values
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet')
for index, prop in obj_properties.items():
    v = (prop['Rotated Angle'] - min_angle) / range_angle
    r, g, b, a = [int(x) for x in cmap(v, bytes=True)]
    color_input = (b, g, r)
    colormap_image = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, index, color_input, 2)

plt.imshow(colormap_image, cmap=cmap)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels([])  # vertically oriented colorbar
cbar.set_label('Angle (Degree)')
plt.show()

# save the boundary, ellipse, and colormap image
plt.imsave(boundary_output, boundary, cmap="gray")
cv2.imwrite(ellipse_output, ellipse_image)
colormap_image = plt.savefig(colormap_output)
# cv2.imwrite(colormap_output, colormap_image)
print("Saved contours, boundaries, ellipse and colormap as images and csv")
```

These are the images I used.
[patch_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkyKD.png)
[patch_mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JUnA.png)

I got this.
[patch_colormap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/albWz.png)

How can I show the rotated angle based on each contour? For example, within each boundary, I want to add the text of its rotated angle.

Like this:
[edited_patch_colormap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X4K3.png)

Comment: Fit ellipses to each white region in your mask and get the angle of the major axis from the return values. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf259efaad93098103d6c27b9e4900ffa There are several methods to fit ellipses.

Comment: Yes, I did that but I would like to show the angles as a text within the image. @fmw42

Comment: See cv2.putText() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576 and draw the text at the center of the ellipse.